# How to displaying categories in the cart Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Question on Woocommerce. In the cart need to divide the products into categories. For example...

Category 1

product 1 - $10.

product 2 - $20.

Category 2

product 1 - $10.

product 2 - $20.

There is a variant `<? Php echo $ _product-> get_categories (); ?>`
But the problem is that categories are displayed before each product:

Category 1

product 1 - $10.

Category 1

product 2 - $20.

Help solve this problem. Thanks!

Code cart.php:

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_contents' ); ?>

        <?php
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $_product   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
            $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

            if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                ?>                  

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <?php echo $_product-> get_categories (); ?>                        
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item <?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">



                    <td class="product-remove">
                        <?php
                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
                                '<a href="%s" class="remove" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">&times;</a>',
                                esc_url( WC()->cart->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                                __( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
                                esc_attr( $product_id ),
                                esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
                            ), $cart_item_key );
                        ?>
                    </td>

                    <td class="product-thumbnail">
                        <?php
                            $thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                            if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
                                echo $thumbnail;
                            } else {
                                printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $thumbnail );
                            }
                        ?>
                    </td>                                                   

                    <td class="product-name" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">             
                        <div><?php
                            if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;';
                            } else {
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $_product->get_name() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                            }

                            // Meta data
                            echo WC()->cart->get_item_data( $cart_item );

                            // Backorder notification
                            if ( $_product->backorders_require_notification() && $_product->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) ) {
                                echo '<p class="backorder_notification">' . esc_html__( 'Available on backorder', 'woocommerce' ) . '</p>';
                            }
                        ?></div>
                        <div><?php  the_field('weight',$product_id); ?></div>
                    </td>                                           

                    <td class="product-price" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                        <?php
                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                        ?>
                    </td>

                    <td class="product-quantity" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                        <?php
                            if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) {
                                $product_quantity = sprintf( '1 <input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $cart_item_key );
                            } else {
                                $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
                                    'input_name'  => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                                    'input_value' => $cart_item['quantity'],
                                    'max_value'   => $_product->get_max_purchase_quantity(),
                                    'min_value'   => '0',
                                ), $_product, false );
                            }

                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item );
                        ?>
                    </td>

                    <td class="product-subtotal" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                        <?php
                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item['quantity'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                        ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>      

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_contents' ); ?>
```

Comment: can you post your code what you have tried?

Comment: File /cart.php
Wrote just below. All code was not placed in the comment.

Comment: You can update the code in your question part.

Comment: Yes, I have already updated my question.

Comment: this cart.php file is located in theme folder?

Comment: Of course mytheme/woocommerce/cart/cart.php
Сategories are shown in the cart, but I need to...

Category 1

product 1 - $10.
product 2 - $20.

Category 2
product 1 - $10.
product 2 - $20.